# Timestamp from an Android app is vastly different from that from a Java app despite the devices being in sync

Tags: java, android, timestamp, adb, android-sensors

I have an `android` service that runs on background, sample sensors and write them to a file with their `time-stamp`.

I have also a `java` application that read from this `file`, and want to compare the time now with the `time-stamp` from the file.

My `android` device `time` set to my PC time, but:
The `time-stamp` (on milli seconds) are different from my java time.

Any one have an idea how to compare the different times?

**Java:**

> System.currentTimeMillis()
>   1460272414374

**Android:**
  `/**
     * The time in nanosecond at which the event happened
     */
      public long timestamp;`

> event.timestamp: 190174864000

Thanks

Comment: pleas add what u tried so far??

Comment: time is time, no matter how it looks like, post the format of those time stamp so we can see how can we compare them

Comment: please post what format of `timestamp` you used ? there is so many time format out there.. @rachel

Comment: I add times examples.

Comment: How did you take the time stamp on Android? Does not seem to be `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: 190174864000  = GMT: Sun, 11 Jan 1976 02:21:04 GMT  whereas other is of todays date

Comment: what is the country set in your android phone

Comment: how can i get which country i have?

Comment: Can you refer me to the useful and clear answer? @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: Due to you still not having provided missing required info as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526935/timestamp-from-an-android-app-is-vastly-different-from-that-from-a-java-app-desp?noredirect=1#comment60658231_36526935, I cannot.

Comment: on java I use `System.currentTimeMillis()` on android I get the timestamp from the SensorEvent object

Comment: do anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
long timeInMillis = (new Date()).getTime() 
                + (sensorEvent.timestamp - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L;

 SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() is the API . sensorTimeStamp in device's local time reference = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((event.timestamp-SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos())/1000000L)
```

private long sensorTimeReference = 0l;
private long myTimeReference = 0l;

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
// set reference times
if(sensorTimeReference == 0l && myTimeReference == 0l) {
    sensorTimeReference = event.timestamp;
    myTimeReference = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
// set event timestamp to current time in milliseconds
event.timestamp = myTimeReference + 
    Math.round((event.timestamp - sensorTimeReference) / 1000000.0);
// some code...
 }
```

Comment: can you give me some explanations? the first code should be on the android service? to save with this the time stamp?

Comment: sorry for the questions... I see the code on `onSensorChange`. but what with the first code? what O need to do with the `timeInMillis` variable? and I didn't also understand the explanation with API.